# two smooth structure given to open subset of manifold are equal

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Given $M$ as a smooth manifold ,denote the smooth structure on it by $\mathcal{A}$.(where smooth structure is a maximal closure of collection of smooth compatible chart that covers $M$)

Here are two representation for smooth structure given to open subset $U\subset M$ .one is:

$$\mathcal{A}_U = \{(V,\phi)\in \mathcal{A}\mid V\subset U\} \tag{1}$$

Another one is :

$$\mathcal{A}_U = \{(V\cap U,\phi|_V) \mid (V,\phi) \in \mathcal{A}\}\tag{2}$$

They are equal correct as I prove below:

$(V\cap U,\phi|_V)$ must lies in $\mathcal{A}$ since it smooth compatible with all element in $\mathcal{A}$ by maximality of it,we know it must lies in it hence all the element in (2) lies in (1).Conversly direction is obvious,is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Can you state precisely the definition of smooth structure in your post?

Comment: @Arctic Char smooth structure here  is a maximal closure of collection of smooth compatible chart that covers M(or simply maximal closure of some given smooth altalas on M),where maximal means any chart on the manifold that compatible with $\mathcal{A}$ must  sit inside $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: Yes it is correct.